# Node.js receiving data from a python script

Tags: python, node.js

So I have node calling a python scrip but I want to get an object back from python.

I'm currently using Python-shell (https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) but the problem is its listening so I can't actually send the data I get from it

```
    shell.on('message', function(message){
            ah = message;
            console.log(message);
            console.log("#");

});

    console.log(ah);
    var host = {
        "hostName":ah
    };
    console.log(host);
    return response.send(200, host);
```

the last section of the code will execute well before the python script returns anything via print() 
(I also can't put the response.send in the listening function because it may send every time the python script prints)

is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the results of a script to the client, just wrap this call:  PythonShell.run in in a router endpoint:

```
app.get('/somepath', (req, res)=>{

 PythonShell.run('my_script.py', options, function (err, results) {
      if (err) throw err;
      // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution 
      res.send('results: %j', results);
    });

});
```

Comment: hmm that mgiht work, I'll try it out and get back to you.